# Arm Cortex Bootloader debugging tips

Tags: python, c, uart, bootloader

I'm writing a serial bootloader for a Cortex-M4 MCU ([ATSAME51N20A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001507E.pdf)) on a custom board. I'm currently flashing/debugging it with a Jlink via SWD.

**Current architecture**: I have a python script that reads in a binary file, breaks it up into 512 byte chunks, sends it over UART to the MCU and at the end does a CRC32 of the whole thing and checks to make sure the CRC at the receiving end matches up. This is all working fine, the data is sent and the CRC's on either end match up.

The incoming binary file is getting saved to address `#define APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS 0x8000`. Once the bootloader has received the last chunk, it calls the following code:

```
void jumpToApplication(void)
{
    uint32_t applicationMainStackPointer = *(volatile uint32_t *) (APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS);
    __set_MSP(applicationMainStackPointer);

    void (*applicationResetHandler)(void);
    uint32_t applicationResetHandlerAddress = *(volatile uint32_t *) (APPLICATION_START_ADDRESS + 4);
    applicationResetHandler = (void *) applicationResetHandlerAddress;
    applicationResetHandler();
}
```

**The problem:** The application isn't running after the bootloader. I should be seeing a bunch of `Hello, World!`'s pop up, but nothing is happening.

I thought maybe jumping to the application with the JLink still attached would cause issues, so I've tried running everything with no JLink attached, and it still doesn't work.

**My questions:**

1. What sort of things might be going wrong here? What can I look into to continue debugging this issue?
2. I've tested the binary I'm sending over my flashing it over JLink, however the file I'm actually flashing is an `.elf` file. As I understand it, the `.bin` file should work just as well, but maybe this is where I'm going wrong?
3. In Python, I'm formatting the binary file like this:

```
   data = [x for x in open(path, 'rb').read()]
   blocks = [data[i:i + PAGE_SIZE] for i in range(0, len(data), PAGE_SIZE)]
```

Could this be corrupting the binary file?

Any debugging tips/advice/insights are appreciated.

Comment: Didn't ypu fprget about the vector table change

Comment: Did you change the app linker script?

Comment: No I didn't. What change is necessary?

Comment: your app code (vector table) has to start from the app start address. Otherwise all addresses are wrong, interrupt handlers are wrong etc etc.

Comment: Changing the linker script worked. Thanks!